# Astroquery SIMBAD : Obtaining coordinates for all frames

Tags: python, astropy, astroquery

I'm trying to obtain coordinates for all frames using the `Simbad` class from `astroquery`, just like it is shown on the [SIMBAD web page](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-basic?Ident=Betelgeuse&submit=SIMBAD+search)
(Basic data section)

I have the following code :

```
from astroquery.simbad import Simbad

def get():
    Simbad.reset_votable_fields()
    Simbad.remove_votable_fields('coordinates')

    Simbad.add_votable_fields('ra(:;A;ICRS;J2000)', 'dec(:;D;ICRS;2000)')
    Simbad.add_votable_fields('ra(:;A;FK5;J2000)', 'dec(:;D;FK5;2000)')

    table = Simbad.query_object("Betelgeuse", wildcard=False)
```

but I'm getting the error:

> KeyError: 'ra(:;A;FK5;J2000): field already present. Fields ra,dec,id,otype, and bibcodelist can only be specified once.  To change their options, first remove the existing entry, then add a new one.'

Everything I could find in the doc about manipulating votable fields, especially coordinates is this :

http://astroquery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simbad/simbad.html#specifying-the-format-of-the-included-votable-fields

Is there a way to get coordinates for all frames sending one query to SIMBAD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of querying multiple coordinates (which seems impossible with astroquery) from SIMBAD you could convert the coordinates by using [`astropy.coordinates.SkyCoord`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.coordinates.SkyCoord.html#skycoord).

For example:

```
from astroquery.simbad import Simbad
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord

Simbad.reset_votable_fields()
Simbad.remove_votable_fields('coordinates')
Simbad.add_votable_fields('ra(:;A;ICRS;J2000)', 'dec(:;D;ICRS;2000)')
table = Simbad.query_object("Betelgeuse", wildcard=False)
coords = SkyCoord(ra=['{}h{}m{}s'.format(*ra.split(':')) for ra in table['RA___A_ICRS_J2000']], 
                  dec=['{}d{}m{}s'.format(*dec.split(':')) for dec in table['DEC___D_ICRS_2000']],
                  frame='icrs', equinox='J2000')
```

Which is a now a SkyCoord object that can be transformed to other frames:

```
>>> coords
<SkyCoord (ICRS): (ra, dec) in deg
    ( 88.79293875,  7.40706389)>
>>> coords.fk4
<SkyCoord (FK4: equinox=J2000.000, obstime=B1950.000): (ra, dec) in deg
    ( 88.79274075,  7.40705223)>
>>> coords.fk5
<SkyCoord (FK5: equinox=J2000.000): (ra, dec) in deg
    ( 88.79294545,  7.40705842)>
```

This can be converted to strings again, for example in `hms dms` formatting:

```
>>> coords.fk5.to_string('hmsdms')
['05h55m10.3069s +07d24m25.4103s']
```

If you want these as additional columns in your table, you can simply add these:

```
>>> table['RA FK5'] = coords.fk5.ra
>>> table['DEC FK5'] = coords.fk5.dec
>>> table['FK4'] = coords.fk4.to_string('hmsdms')
>>> table
 MAIN_ID  RA___A_ICRS_J2000 DEC___D_ICRS_2000     RA FK5       DEC FK5                 FK4             
               "h:m:s"           "d:m:s"           deg           deg     
--------- ----------------- ----------------- ------------- ------------- -----------------------------
* alf Ori     05:55:10.3053     +07:24:25.430 88.7929454548 7.40705841559 05h55m10.2578s +07d24m25.388s
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! Didn't know I can actually convert from one frame to another with astropy.

Answer (score 1):

For reasons I can't determine, astroquery did not support multiple configurable added VO options.  It will soon, though: see [this pull request](https://github.com/astropy/astroquery/pull/820).  There were no problems with the code you posted, just a bug in astroquery.